# Energy used to run Tezos

Tags: node, baker

What is an order of magnitude of the energy used today to run the whole Tezos network and how does it compare to other major crypto currencies ?

It should be insignificant since there's no proof of work and obviously we don't have access to all the data but do we have a good upper bound?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are approx 450 bakers at the moment. If you assume each is running an average desktop which runs at 100W (this is almost certainly too high but if you are looking for an upper bound it's probably good enough) then the energy consumed in a given day to secure the network is 450 * 24 * 100 / 1000 = 1,080 kilowatt hours.

Bitcoin by comparison uses about a million times more energy 1,380M kWh according to - https://www.ofnumbers.com/2018/08/26/how-much-electricity-is-consumed-by-bitcoin-bitcoin-cash-ethereum-litecoin-and-monero/

Comment: I'm running 6 nodes in addition to a laptop, so a bit higher for many bakers  Still hardly worth mentioning compared to any PoW chain 